# Counting objects using Static

Tags: java, static

I'm having trouble making this work. I have to keep the Driver1 exactly the same. What do I need to do with my StaticCounter class?

```
public class Driver1
{
public static void main(String[] args)
   {
   for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
      {
         System.out.println("Counter returned: " +
         StaticCounter.count());
      }
   }
}
```

---

```
StaticCounter.java
public class StaticCounter
{
   public static int count()
   {
       static int id;
       id=count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please try to clarify your question. What exactly are you trying to do? It's not clear to me. When writing questions, you will want to write them keeping in mind that we are initially completely ignorant of your goals, your code, and your problem, and only understand that which you explain to us or show us.

Comment: The goal is to write a StaticCounter class with a static int count() method that starts at zero, and returns consecutive integers with each call (starting at zero). I know I have the Driver1 class correct, but I can't figure out how to do the StaticCounter class.

Comment: In this case there are some very obvious errors, but for future reference you should explain **how**  it's not working (including an error messages, if appropriate) and what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Please edit your original question, and put that information in there for all to see, as many skip comments.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are probably looking for something like:

```
public class StaticCounter{

    private static int count;

    public static int count(){
        return count++; //or ++count if you want to increment before getting value
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class StaticCounter{
    private static int count = 0;

    public static int count(){
        count = count+1;
        return count;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this any different from the answer that was already provided?

Comment: Using different increment (I assume the asker new in programming), and also write initialization explicitly (based on the same assumption)

Comment: Alright, fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

your Main:

```
public class Driver1
{
public static void main(String[] args)
   {
   public StaticCounter static = new StaticCounter();
   for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
      {
         System.out.println("Counter returned: " + count(i));
      }
   }
}
```

and the class StaticCounter

```
public class StaticCounter{

    private int count;

    public StaticCounter(){
        countt = 0;
    }

    public static int count(int i){
        count = i;
    }

}
```